# read non-xml file from BaseX database

Tags: xquery, basex

How can I read a non-XML (specifically CSV) file that is stored in a BaseX database from a query?
`csv:doc()` expects a URI, how do I point it to a file inside the database?

Answer (score 1):

Ooh, I think I got it:

```
csv:parse(convert:binary-to-string(db:retrieve("db", "path/to/file.csv"), 'UTF-8')
```

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: You are right, that’s currently the only way. `db:retrieve` could possibly be replaced with something like `db:raw-text` and `db:raw-binary`; we thought about that in the past. Thanks for the observation.